# Writing Linear Complex Equations from two points

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm just wondering how I write, suppose a line that goes through origin and point $z=a+bi$ into equation form?

Comment: You could use two points (0,0) and (a,b)...

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Pretend that you are working in $\mathbb{R^2}$ rather than $\mathbb{C}.$

One form of the general equation for a line is $y = mx + b.$

From the information given, you have enough to solve for $m$ and $b$.

Comment: Sorry I meant in complex space, and how to write the equation of the line connecting the origin to $z=a+bi$ in terms of $z$

Comment: @Mathsexplorer Translate $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $x =$ the real part of $z =$ Re$(z)$.  Translate $y =$ the imaginary part of $z =$ Im$(z)$.